# Why deleting one partition caused my system to break

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have deleted the highlighted partition because it was supposed to be "unused". Then my Windows wouldn't boot. It said that required media is not present. Can you explain why this happened?

This is the layout (nieprzydzielony stands for unallocated):

[image]

I thought I'm not deleting the startup partition of Windows 10.

Please note that I'm not asking how to recover from the situation. I have already restored a backup and my system works fine.